# How to clone the value of a hidden input and append to another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Is there a way to get the value of a hidden div and clone the value to another div? I have a color picker in a ACF option page and am looking for a way show what that color would look like in another div.

To put it in another way if the value of a hidden input has #2b0059, it gets the value and copies it to another div.

My code so far:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).on( "click", '#update', function() {      $("#color1").clone().appendTo("#output .acf-input")
    });
});
```

```css
.acf-input {height:100px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color1">
<input type="hidden" name="acf[field_60d4d8ef09c78]" value="#2b0059">
</div>
<div id ="output">
  <div class="acf-input"></div>
</div>
<button id="update">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't actually need to `clone` it, so how about just getting the value and adding a css background-color to the div ?
Something like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).on( "click", '#update', function() {
      $('.acf-input').css({
        backgroundColor: $('#color1 input').val()
      })
    });
});
```

```css
.acf-input {height:100px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color1">
<input type="hidden" name="acf[field_60d4d8ef09c78]" value="#2b0059">
</div>
<div id ="output">
  <div class="acf-input"></div>
</div>
<button id="update">Update</button>
```

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't think to do it this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple you just need a proper selector.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     
    $(document).on( "click", '#update', function() {   
      var clonedObj=$("#color1 input").clone();
      $("#output .acf-input").append(clonedObj);
      console.log($(".acf-input").html());
      alert("cloned")
    });
});
```

```css
.acf-input {height:100px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color1">
  <input type="hidden" name="acf[field_60d4d8ef09c78]" value="#2b0059">
</div>
<div id ="output">
  <div class="acf-input"></div>

</div>
<button id="update">Update</button>
```